# Azure PowerShell - can't create a share

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage

I want to use Azure storage as backup for my static files. I installed Azure PowerShell and connected to my subscription follow to this guide: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/install-configure-powershell/

Next step I went to my Azure portal and created storage:
[image]

Then I copied a primary storage key

[image]

and executed the command

```
$ctx=New-AzureStorageContext account-name account-key
```

with my storage account name (first field on image above) and primary account key.
It's ok.

Then I try to create a share and get the error:

```
PS C:\> $s=New-AzureStorageShare mysd -Context $ctx
New-AzureStorageShare : The remote name could not be resolved: 'myxxxbackup.file.core.windows.net'
At line:1 char:4
+ $s=New-AzureStorageShare mysd -Context $ctx
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureStorageShare], StorageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.File.Cmdlet.NewAzureStorageShare
```

Why and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Have you enabled `Azure File Service` in your subscription? Since it is in `Preview` currently, I believe you would need to do that first (at least that's what I did in my subscription).

To do so, go to accounts (https://account.windowsazure.com/Subscriptions) --> preview features --> Windows Azure Files. Once it is enabled, you should be able to access Azure File Service.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please first verify the storage account name you were using is correct. "myxxxbackup" seems not a valid storage account name as if I do >nslookup myxxxbackup.blob.core.windows.net, it can't be resolved.

If the account name is correct, can you see if there is the new Azure File endpoint under your storage account in the Azure Management Portal (besides the blob/table/queue ones)

Regards, Jason

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, will be happy to follow the guideline. However as I don't have 50 reputation yet, it seems I can't leave a comment below the original post, what shall I do if I want request a clarification from the author?

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger, but your question [is answered here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258610/419956).